# How to Do the next process when i am click the button in bot framework by using Thumbnail Card

Tags: bots, botframework

I am developing one bot frame work project in that I have some requirement is like below.
       whenever I click the button in Thumbnail card next I want to display the List of Items in horizontally after displayed the List of items, Next I click on any one List of item it will be redirected to My Own URL.

Present I am displaying Thumbnail Card like below 
[image]

Now I want to display the list like below when I am click the button
[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the current channels support arbitrary card designs as of yet, so you are limited to the set provided by the channel (i.e. Skype, Facebook, Telegram, etc.)